# Codeigniter get_where categories id = forums id

Tags: php, codeigniter

how can i create a relation between categories and forums in codeigniter? First im getting all the categories, put them inside an array, and then display them on my forums like this:

```
        // $this->db->order_by('category_position', 'asc');
        // $q = $this->db->get('categories');
        // return $q->result_array();
```

This works perfectly. Next how should i go in order to get all the forums, related to a category? How exactly should i use codeigniter's get_where - and then state where forum id = category id from another method?

My database is simple and contains the following:

```
        // For categories: category_id, category_position, category_title
        // For forums: forum_id, forum_position, forum_title
```

Comment: can you provide a picture. I did not understand.

Comment: sure, there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned no CSS Grid or bootstrap, can you use flex? If so you can do:

```css
.fluid-parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
}

.fixed-child {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.fluid-child {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="fluid-parent">
  <div class="fixed-child"></div>
  <div class="fluid-child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello, I re-wrote my question. Can you delete your answer? and maybe even help me out? Thanks

Comment: You should post a new question instead of editing an old question to be totally different. You'll have a much better chance of getting an answer by posting a new question.

Comment: yea but my acc froze and i had to edit the question which demoted me. Anyway i researched in the codeigniter forum and could not find the bast way to do what i want.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to absolutely position the div with set width. And add the same size to the containers' padding to offset the second div accordingly.

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  /*Width of the left div*/
  position: relative;
}

.left {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  background-color: blue;
}

div {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```